# What is a "Javascript Bootloader"?

Tags: javascript, facebook, bootloader

I have seen this mainly in the source of Facebook `Bootloader.setResourceMap({"bMxb7":{"name":....` What is exactly a bootloader in javascript?  What is its use and purpose?

Comment: This is not part of JavaScript.. Bootloader is simply one object created for Facebook' internal js library..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking, the bootloader is a (relatively) small amount of code responsible for establishing the environment that all subsequent code requires to run, as such it is also the the first code to be executed. It's usually restricted to OSes, but makes sense for FB too.

In the case of Facebook, the bootloader will do things like loading additional JS files and other resources that the library needs in addition to the single public `<script />` the developer included in the document.

Answer (score 16):

Bootloader is an important part of Facebook's front-end code, which allows Javascript libraries to be lazy-loaded as needed instead of on page load. A couple of Facebook developers [go into further detail here](http://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=596368660334&ref=mf) if you'd like to know more.

You can use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), [LABjs](http://labjs.com/) or [others](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1) to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, there is no such thing.

A bootstrap loader (which is the full name of the term) is the part of an operating system that loads the disk operating system from disk, thus the computer lifts itself by the bootstraps, by loading from disk before the disk loading routines are loaded.

There are no Javascript operating systems, so there is no bootstrap loader for Javascript. This is just some object that is named that way, presumably because it does something early in the page load process.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: sorry for this late comment. I voted down your answer because the question was "what is bootloader" not "bootstrap loader". There is really a bootloader in facebook, the team developed to deploy and download the js files easily and faster in the browser. Please don't get it wrong. And again thanks for your response.

Comment: @maksbd19: Thanks for the reply. However, the downvote is unjust, because boot loader is just short for bootstrap loader. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booting There may be something that they call a "javascript boot loader", but that doesn't make it an a actual boot loader.

Comment: you got your point. But you should mention it in your answer. People like me might lack that knowledge of 'bootstrap loader'. Anyway  now I cant undo my downvote unless you edit your answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Here is a video from React.js Conf 2016 that touches on what Bootloader is. But to summarize: Bootloader helps improve the performance of the app but not downloading content unless they are actually needed. The video has the example of the 'share button'

https://youtu.be/SnAq9tbeRm4?t=17m16s