# How to simulate a full browser's request to an HTML document?

Tags: http, browser, language-agnostic, html-parsing, simulation

## Goal

I want to simulate with a request to a HTML-document just the way a browser does. This means I not only want to download the main HTML file but also linked stuff like CSS, JS, images.

For now I only want to parse the first HTML document. I.e. I am not taking requests into account which result from parsing say the CSS (background-images, web-fonts) or JavaScript (Ajax) etc.

To implement this I need to know how a browser exactly processes a website. I haven't found a good reference on that. Any help on that would be greatly appreciated and likely solve my problem.

## Assumption

As I lacked any good references I assumed the process (without taking redirects, the rendering etc. into account) works like that:

1. A persistent HTTP-connection is established with `www.facebook.com`
2. The Path "/" is requested and the HTML is received
3. When the the document is fully (?) received it is parsed and a list of URLs that need to be requested is filled (divided into head and body objects?!)
4. The first URL is taken from the head-list and it is checked whether a persistent HTTP-connection is established with that host

   - If there is not, it is established and the afterwards the Object is requested
   - If there is, it is added to the connection's "download queue"
5. Step 4 is repeated until the list is empty
6. Then Steps 4-5 are repeated for the "body list"

Is this even close to how a browser works?

**Bonus question:** Does the order of JavaScript and CSS files in the header make a difference?

## Doubts

I conducted a few tests with the Chrome Developer Tools (Chrome 18) to confirm. I connected to `www.facebook.com` measuring when each Object was loaded. When reloading using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> the results looked like this:

[image: Output in the Chrome-Developer-Network-Tab for a request to www.facebook.com]

What puzzles me the most is that most requests are concurrent to others even when from the same host (`static.ak.fbcdn.net`). Pipelining is disabled my browser (which is the default setting) so why are the request still seem to happen simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers do use multiple connections, in order to speed up the downloading (parallel downloading of resources). They limit however the number of connections to the same host, which is one of the reasons for the existence of content-delivery networks.

The order of CSS and Script files in the header do matter, as [scripts block parallel downloading](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rtt#PutStylesBeforeScripts) (unless the script is not defered).

Also browsers parse HTML while they receive it (again to speed up things) - this is a reason if you put a script in the head that tries to manipulate DOM elements not yet loaded, you'll get an error.

But all of this are browser implementation details that may not be important for your task.
Best - look at the source code of some headless browser to find what's going on.

Comment: Thanks! You're absolutely right about the parallel downloading. Just confirmed that with wireshark.

I also agree on the order part. I would after conducting a few experiments add though that the _execution_ not the _downloading_ of js blocks parallel downloading. Thus in my case I will just ignore that fact.

Do you have any information regarding the download order of scripts in the head compared to ones in the body? It seems that Chrome makes no difference there. The screenshot seems to prove otherwise but in reality FB [lazy-loads](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4139432/30344) some resources.

Comment: @Caffeine a lot of useful information can be found in the [Page Speed Documents](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rules_intro). I've just updated my answer with a link, explaining that script do actually block downloading of stylesheet in many browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's full of useful information indeed. They also link to [browserscope](http://www.browserscope.org) which has some good browser comparisons regarding their network behaviour.